# How to navigate to home screen after successfully login in flutter and appwrite?

Tags: authentication, navigation, appwrite

I have created a login app using flutter and appwrite.my problem is when I click login button, app navigate in to home page whether username and password correct or not. I have added code segment bellow. Please help me to solve om problem.

```
class AuthRepo extends BaseAuthRepo {
  late Client client;
  late Account account;
  final SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager();

  AuthRepo() {
    client = Client();
    client
        .setEndpoint('https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1')
        .setProject('645e0e30frgff3c94e434');
    account = Account(client);
  }
  @override
  Future<void> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await account.createEmailSession(email: email, password: password);
      final user = await account.get();
      await sessionManager.setLogedIn(true);
        } catch (error) {
    
      log("signin in error${error.toString()}");
    }
  }
```

login screen.dart

```
InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  try {
                     _authRepo.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: _email.text, password: _password.text);

                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => MyHomePage())));
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
```